# Scip: Maximum time option missing?

Tags: time, max, scip

I'm using a software based on SCIP (3.0.1). I have a bunch of experiments to execute, and for that I'd like to simply enforce a maximum execution time for SCIP: if you haven't already found the best solution, after x seconds outputs anyway the best solution found so far.

Right now I'm doing using a script that sends to the bound PID process the sigint interrupt after the desired time, but it isn't working all the time. I'd like to properly code this with SCIP. Simply as it may sound, I couldn't find a relevant option for doing that.

Do you have any idea?

Kind regards for your time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a time limit parameter for setting a solving time in seconds:

```
SCIPsetRealParam(scip, "limits/time", 600)
```

sets this limit to 10 minutes.

A list of all parameters is found in the [SCIP documentation](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that also via settings. Either in the interactive shell:

```
set limits time <your_timelimit>
```

or in a settings file, that you read in before solving:

```
limits/time = <your_timelimit>
```

Comment: The use of the settings file worked perfectly! Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Then please mark this question as answered. Welcome to stackoverflow!